# How to transform some plain text output into JSON using some rules?

Tags: python, python-2.7, data-processing

I'm parsing an output of a program that prints two words a line and these words can be duplicated. The output is sorted.

```
a  1
a  2
b  5
c  6
c  6
d  3
e  1
e  1
e  2
f  0
```

I want to create a dict that looks like this (using the input data I provided):

```
[
  {"name": "a", numbers: [{"number": "1", "duplicated": false},
                          {"number": "2", "duplicated": false}]},
  {"name": "b", numbers: [{"number": "5", "duplicated": false}],
  {"name": "c", numbers: [{"number": "6", "duplicated": true}],
  {"name": "d", numbers: [{"number": "3", "duplicated": false}],
  {"name": "e", numbers: [{"number": "1", "duplicated": true},
                          {"number": "2", "duplicated": false}]},
  {"name": "f", numbers: [{"number": "0", "duplicated": false}],
]
```

How can I achieve this? If possible, without using anything but standard library.

Everything I've tried looks big, monstrous and ugly.

There's no code as I could not get any result.

Comment: Please tell how are you parsing the output? parsing from a file or some other source?

Comment: Is that relevant? I'm using subprocess.PIPE.

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't want a dictionary like `{'a':{1:0, 2:0}, 'b':{5:0}, 'c':{6:1}, 'd':{3:0}, 'e':{1:1, 2:0}, 'f':{0:0}}` – _"Simple is better than complex."_ and _"Flat is better than nested."_

Comment: That structure goes to the frontend. Also I didn't provide the full structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could build a dict like `{name_a: {value1: count1, value2:count2} ...}`, then generate your output from it:

```
from collections import defaultdict

name_to_values = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(int))
with open('data.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        name, value = line.split()
        name_to_values[name][value] += 1

out = []
for name in name_to_values:
    d = {'name': name}
    d['numbers'] = [{'number': value, 'duplicated': count > 1 }
                    for value, count in name_to_values[name].items()]
    out.append(d)
```

Output:

```
print(out)

# [{'name': 'a', 'numbers': [{'number': '1', 'duplicated': False}, {'number': '2', 'duplicated': False}]},
#  {'name': 'b', 'numbers': [{'number': '5', 'duplicated': False}]}, 
#  {'name': 'c', 'numbers': [{'number': '6', 'duplicated': True}]},
#  {'name': 'd', 'numbers': [{'number': '3', 'duplicated': False}]},
#  {'name': 'e', 'numbers': [{'number': '1', 'duplicated': True}, 
#  {'number': '2', 'duplicated': False}]}, 
#  {'name': 'f', 'numbers': [{'number': '0', 'duplicated': False}]}]
```

Answer (score 0):

First, simplify the output by storing it in a dictionary, and utilize it later to produce the expected output like below:

```
from pprint import pprint

lines ="""a  1
a  2
b  5
c  6
c  6
d  3
e  1
e  1
e  2
f  0"""

d = dict()
for line in lines.split("\n"):
    name, number = line.strip().split()
    if d.get(name):
        d[name].append(number)
    else:
        d[name] = [number]

results = []
for name, numbers in d.items():
    number_list = []
    for num in set(numbers):
        number_list.append({
            'number': num,
            'duplicated': str(numbers.count(num)>1),
        })
    results.append({
        'name': name,
        'numbers': number_list,
        })
pprint(results)
```